# How should i design my session

Tags: php

Currently, i am designing a website selling some products which would has a function to arithmetic calculation of the prices of items added to cart. The file is called cart.php and it has a function which display the session variable (total price) and this function could be used in other pages of my website.

The cart.php code is as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($addid))
{
    $quantity = mysql_query("SELECT id, quantity FROM product WHERE id=$addid");
    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)){
        if  ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.$addid]){
        $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] +='1';
        }
    }
    header('Location: '.$page);
}
...
function cart(){
...
$_SESSION['totalamount'] = $total;
...
echo 'Total: $'.$total.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

I would like to create a log in screen which allows members to log in (login.php) and the ability to logout(logout.php).

Therefore my question is this:

If the session is the same throughout the web application, then can i put the `session_start();` in login.php (this means starting a session right after user has been verified) and `session_destroy()` once user clicks logout(logout.php)? In this case, do i still need the session_start() inside cart.php?

Answer (score 0):

When you want use session you should write session_start().

For best capability call session_name('mysession');
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

PHP code:

```
session_name('mysession');
session_start();
```